# running requestAnimationFrame from within a new object

Tags: javascript, three.js, requestanimationframe

I'm having trouble running an animation. This is inside `var ob1 = function() {};`. When called, it runs for a while and then I get the error `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`. However, this same structure has no problems running outside of the object.

```
/////////////// Render the scene ///////////////
this.render = function (){

        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        if(isControls == true) controls.update(clock.getDelta());
        this.animate();
        //console.log(true);
        requestAnimationFrame(this.render());
}

/////////////// Update objects ///////////////
this.animate = function (){
        console.log("!");
}
```

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` expects a callback, you're just passing `undefined`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should pass a function reference to `requestAnimationFrame`, not invoke the function:

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.render);
```

Since you're using `this` inside `render`, you'll probably need [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
```

Your version is causing a Stack Overflow (the function is calling itself synchronously, until the call stack is full).

---

Comment: That's actually what I tried first, because that's what I normally do, but it doesn't work. It runs only 1 time and tells me this.animate() doesn't exist, after running this.animate(). If I put it as the first thing, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Type error cleanedupmenufunctions.php:167
render`

Comment: I just updated my answer, you need a bound function, with a fixed `this` value.

Comment: Ah, the line `requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));` works great! No errors after several refreshes.

Comment: Note that bind is not supported on older browsers. The MDN link I provided includes a polyfill.

Comment: You don't want to use bind this way as you're creating a new function object every time you call bind. Instead you want to bind beforehand at init time as in `const render = this.render.bind(this);` then in your loop call `requestAnimationFrame(render)`. You could also do it the react way, in your constructor do `this.render = this.render.bind(this);` then you can call `requestAnimationFrame(this.render);`

Answer (score 0):

Something I did to get this to run from a class that I saw from another example was to do this.

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.animate()
})
```

This seems to get around the issue as well without any issues!

Here is a threeJS example of me using this from within a class

https://jsfiddle.net/gentleman_goat66/o5wn3bpf/107/