# ThreeJS as AngularJS Scope Object - requestAnimationFrame doesn't recognize callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js, angularjs-scope, requestanimationframe

Morning,

I'm doing some experiments to revise my JS knowledge, figure out what AngularJS can do/is for, and get a grip on ThreeJS - normally I write OpenGL/MFC in C++, but I've written a little php/js/html5 in the past.

I'm trying to wrap some ThreeJS in an AngularJS Controller's `$scope` object.

The error in the Chrome JS debugger is

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'requestAnimationFrame' on 'Window': The callback provided as parameter 1 is not a function'
```

Here's some code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appMain = angular.module("myApp", []);

    appMain.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

        // WebGL via THREEJS
        $scope.threejs = {
            width:640,
            height:480,
            scene: null,
            camera: null,
            renderer: null,
            box:null,
            initialise: function()
            {
                this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
                this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, this.width/this.height, 0.1, 100);
                this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

                this.renderer.setSize(this.width, this.height);

                document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

                // Create a Spinning Cube
                var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:'blue'});

                this.box = new THREE.Mesh(geom, material);

                this.scene.add(this.box);

                this.camera.position.z = 5;
            },
            render: function()
            {
                requestAnimationFrame(this.render);

                this.box.rotation.x += 0.1;
                this.box.rotation.y += 0.1;

                this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
            }
        };

        $scope.threejs.initialise();
        $scope.threejs.render();
    });



</script>
```

..I get a static, non spinning cube - i.e. it renders only once.

I think the error is more related to my misunderstanding of the workings of Javascript than to do with anything much else.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[One of the related questions on the panel on the right suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459449/running-requestanimationframe-from-within-a-new-object?rq=1):

requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));

Now my cube spins. And I am happy. And now I shall do some research around `bind()`.

Comment: If you are using `ES2015` then just wrap your render / animate / whateveryoucallit function with arrow syntax: `() => animate`.